# CSS Transparent buttons with borders

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a button in css like this one

[image]

but I have no idea how to do it as I am new to css. This is what I tried:

```
.gbtnHollow  {
     background:  transparent;
     height:  38px;
     line-height:  40px;
     border:  2px solid white;
     display:  inline-block;
     float:  none;
     text-align:  center;
     width:  120px;
     padding:  0px!important;
     font-size:  14px;
     color:  #fff;
 }

.gbtnHollow:hover  {
     color:  #fff;
     background:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 }
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong there mate, It should work. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ka14L2uk/).

Comment: you want to add something in background as it is in that image ?

Comment: @Harry thanks, i re-opened notepad++ and it fixed itself.

Comment: @TomTriumphentGames: That is kind of strange mate but good to know that your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple, set `background: none;` to button. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0jL56pn/1/)

Answer (score 4):

```
button {
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
}
```

Add this and customize it for you. Example is here on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfypt7yh/3)

Answer (score 4):

[image]
[image]

```
#button {
     width: 150px;
     height: 50px;
     border:none;
     border:solid 2px black;
     border-radius: 5px;
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255,0);
     font-size: 25px;
}

#button:hover {
     background:black;
     color:white; 
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple. add this css to button:

```
button {
    background: none;/*this for transparent button*/
    border: 1px solid black;/* this is for button border*/
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    top: 80px;
}
```